# Resource.resx load dynamically in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, load, resx

I'm making an app where the beginning , before the login , the user can choose the language .
I made 4 different files ,
- Resource.resx
- Resource.IT-it.resx
- Resource.ES-es.resx
- Resource.DE-de.resx

I would like to click the the language file was loaded clicked .
Currently in xaml call so the file :

```
xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyClass.Properties;assembly=MyClass"
Title="{x:Static res:Resources.mynamevariable}"
```

How can I make to click on the tongue , you can recharge the resource file ?
ps .: 4 file containing the same variables , so as to draw the translation easily .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`MyClass.Properties.Resources.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT");`

instead of

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CultureInfo to the culture that the user has selected.  For example to change to Italian you need to use:

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");`

Your resource files should also be named Resources.resx - Resources.it-IT.resx - Resources.es-ES.resx - Resources.de-DE.resx

Comment: i have test it but don't work, set this code before InitializeComponent();

Comment: Your files should also be called Resources.it-IT.resx etc, rather than Resource.IT-it.resx.

Comment: the tutorial set Resource.it-IT.resx

Comment: No it doesn't, it says  Resource**s**.de-DE.resx

Comment: eh fact , it becomes in Italian it-IT

Comment: I have no idea.  Are you getting an exception?  Have you imported System.Globalization?

Comment: public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
        }

but don't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100950/discussion-between-spaceplane-and-mr-developer).

Answer (score 0):

i have solved like:

`myclass.Properties.Resources.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT");`

where it-IT can are de-DE...fr-FR..ecc